# Trouble with php variables and ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

ok I have edited this to another couple of questions I've asked on a similar issue, but I really am in a rush so thought I'd start a new one, sorry if it bothers anyone.

first I have a php script on test.php on the apache server

```
<?php
//create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname");

//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
   echo "failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
$grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($grab);
$name = $row["name"];
$color = $row["color"];
$price = $row["price"];
$n1 = $name[0];
$c1 = $color[0];
$p1 = $price[0];

?>
```

Then I've got this ajax script set to fire onload of page a webpage written in html. so the load() function is onload of the page in the body tag. This script is in the head.

```
function load(){
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.php", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatecahnge = function(){
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
         document.getElementById("itemNameLink1").innerHTML = "<?php echo $n1;?>;
         }
      }
   }
```

ok so what I want is the $n1 variable in the php script to be used in the javascript ajax code. Where the  script is, but I'm not sure where or how to make use of the variable, I've tried a few things. All that happens right now is the innerHTML of itemNameLink1 just disappears.

I'm quite new so any advise would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Since you're using (or claim to be using) jQuery, ditch all the manual `XMLHttpRequest` crap. If you're not using jQuery then fix the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response (this is what you echo in php) returned from request you can get by `responseText` attribute of `XMLHttpRequest` object.
So first your JS code should be:

```
function load(){
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.php", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatecahnge = function(){
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
         document.getElementById("itemNameLink1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
      }
   }
```

now in php echo `$n1` variable:

```
....
$grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($grab);
$name = $row["name"];
$color = $row["color"];
$price = $row["price"];
$n1 = $name[0];
$c1 = $color[0];
$p1 = $price[0];

// echo it to be returned to the request
echo $n1;
```

**Update to use JSON for multiple variables**

so if we do this:

```
$name = $row["name"];
$color = $row["color"];
$price = $row["price"];

$response = array
(
    'name'  => $name,
    'color' => $color,
    'price' => $price
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

Then in javascript we can parse it again to have data object containing 3 variables.

```
var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
//for debugging you can log it to console to see the result
console.log(data);
document.getElementById("itemNameLink1").innerHTML = data.name; // or xmlhttp.responseText to see the response as text
```

**Fetching all the rows:**

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($grab); // this will fetch the data only once
```

you need to cycle through the result-set got from database: also better for performance to use assoc instead of array

```
$names = $color = $price =  array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grab))
{
    $names[] = $row['name'];
    $color[] = $row['color'];
    $price[] = $row['price'];
}

$response = array
(
    'names' => $names,
    'color' => $color,
    'price' => $price
);
```

Comment: this actually worked, I'm gonna have to find another way as I want to work with multiple variables. do have one problem though. for some reason I only get the first letter of the variable string not the whole string. is there some problem with my php coding.

Comment: yes problem is: `$name = $row["name"];` is name and `$n1 = $name[0];` is the first character of that name, so you can just echo `$name`

Comment: surely $row["name"] is the array of names, or how would iget the array of names from the Database.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the PHP variable. And use that variable in your javascript:

```
<?php
    $n1 = "asd";
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <div id="itemNameLink1"></div>

    <script>
        function load()
        {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();                     
            xmlhttp.open('GET', '/test.php', true);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            //Note you used `onreadystatecahnge` instead of `onreadystatechange` 
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("itemNameLink1").innerHTML = '<?=$n1?>';
                }
            }
        }

        load();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do I make sure the php is loaded before the load function.

Comment: Just write it earlier in the file then the javascript. So in this example the variable is defined before the javascript gets executed.

Comment: still not working, I could try the first way. what I did was move everything except the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange part to outside the load function(before), so var ml and xml open and xml send are loaded globally not as part of the load function but still the $n1 variable just doesn't come out at all.

Comment: I think i see what is wrong. First you define `$name` which i think is a string. Then you try access that string as an array with `$name[0]`. Try the javascript code with static data e.g. `$n1 = "This is a test"`, then you can see if the javascript works. If it do, then there is probably something wrong with your variable definition like a said here above.

Comment: no tried changing the php variable to "hello" and still empty string from the function.

Comment: Does it even come through the `if` statement in your javascript? Add `alert('test');` in your `if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)` and check if it's reached.

Comment: yeah because I've tried with just a random string instead of the php variable, say "success" instead of <? =$n1?> and it comes out fine.

Comment: Did you tried the first option with static data? It should work because you just pass your php variable to your javascript function...

Comment: no I'm not really sure how to do it. do you mean to define javascript variables in the php file. I honestly didn't think you could do that.

Comment: No that's not what i meant. Remove the code where you currenty execute the `load` function (in your body onload) and try the first option in my answer. Replace `$n1 = $name[0];` with `$n1 = "this is a test";`

Comment: I tried the first option it just comes back as n1 undefined

Comment: is there another way of using the information stored in that variable in the javascript code. Oh and I will try the other way in the morning. I did it exactly as you said put on here O just didn't remove the onload function.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically generate a javascript document with php that contains server side variables declared as javascript variables, and then link this in the head of your document, and then include this into your document head whenever server side variables are needed. This will also allow you to dynamically update the variable values upon page generation, so for example if you had a nonce or something that needs to change on each page load, the correct value can be passed upon each page load. to do this, you need to do a few things. First, create a php script and declare the correct headers for it to be interpreted as a script:

jsVars.php:

```
<?php
//declare javascript doc type
header("Content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
//tell the request not to cache this file so updated variables will not be incorrect if they change
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.

//create the javascript object
?>

var account = {
    email: <?= $n1; ?>,
    //if you need other account information, you can also add those into the object here
    username: <?= /*some username variable here for example */ ?>
}
```

You can repeat this for any other information you need to pass to javascript on page load, and then reference your data using the namespaced javascript object (using object namespacing will prevent collisions with other script variables that may not have been anticipated.) wherever it is needed as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
//put this wherever you need to reference the email in your javascript, or reference it directly with account.email
var email = account.email;
</script>
```

You can also put a conditional statement into the head of your document so it will only load on pages where it is needed (or if any permission checks or other criteria pass as well). If you load this before your other scripting files, it will be available in all of them, provided you are using it in a higher scope than your request.

```
<head>

<?php
    //set the $require_user_info to true before page render when you require this info in your javascript so it only loads on pages where it is needed.
    if($require_user_info == TRUE): ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" href="http://example.com/path-to-your-script/jsVars.php" />

    <?php endif; ?>

<script type="text/javascript" href="your-other-script-files-that-normally-load" />

</head>
```

You can also do this for any other scripts that have to load under specific criteria from the server.

Comment: You can use a similar approach to return an object from an ajax call if you do not want the data available until after the document loads, though you would want to JSON_ENCODE the response in that case. This will let you fetch additional scripts, variables, etc from the server through ajax that can be dynamically generated on the server based on the criteria passed through the original ajax call.